# Drop content div only in the front-page with XDV

Tags: plone, theming, xdv

I'm trying to remove the content div only for the homepage by this line (in the rules.xml)

```
<drop css:theme="#content" 
      if-content="/html/body[@class='section-front-page']" />
```

It doesn't work ... why? It seems ok for me :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS selectors, too:

```
<drop css:theme="#content" 
      css:if-content="body.section-front-page" />
```

This resolves to the same XPath expression, but it's a lot easier on the eye

Comment: Thank's Martin,
it was my first choice, but it doesn't work.

The html code I have is:
<body class="template-document_view portaltype-document section-front-page icons-on">

Comment: Is the #content div in the theme or the page content from Plone? If it's in the page content then you want to be using `<drop css:content="#content" ...`.

Answer (score 2):

See: http://pivotallabs.com/users/alex/blog/articles/427-xpath-css-class-matching

To use that syntax you would have to match on **all** the classes for the body tag

Use:

```
/html/body[
   contains(
      concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),
      ' section-front-page '
   )
]
```

(works for me in FireBug)

Comment: Note that while **your** front page has "section-front-page" (which is the default for the site), that "section..." name may be different if you select another item to use as the default view for the site root.